# Функция для построчной проверки датафрейм по условию

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan

Есть датафрейм (см. пример). В сериях датафрейма есть пропуски.

Как выполнить проверку на эти пропуски и результаты проверки записать в новую серию d?

```
    a   b   c   d
0   1   -   -   нет числа, нет числа
1   3   4   6   
2   -   7   4   нет числа
3   6   5   -   нет числа
```

Я начал делать так:

- прошелся циклом по каждой серии и собрал все найденные ошибки в список
- далее список перевел в строку с помощью join, хотя может это и не нужно делать
- далее применил данную функцию к датафрейму с помощью метода apply.

В результате рассчитывал получить в каждой строке серии d список пропусков этой же строки из серий a, b и c, но получаю ошибку KeyError.

Что поправить в функции или как по другому можно написать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в DataFrame на месте пропусков находятся знаки минуса:

```
In [27]: df
Out[27]:
   a  b  c
0  1  -  -
1  3  4  6
2  -  7  4
3  6  5  -

In [28]: df['d'] = [', '.join(['нет числа'] * x) for x in df.eq('-').sum(axis=1)]

In [29]: df
Out[29]:
   a  b  c                     d
0  1  -  -  нет числа, нет числа
1  3  4  6
2  -  7  4             нет числа
3  6  5  -             нет числа
```

пошагово:

```
In [178]: df.eq('-')
Out[178]:
       a      b      c
0  False   True   True
1  False  False  False
2   True  False  False
3  False  False   True
```

суммируем `True` (`1`) построчно:

```
In [179]: df.eq('-').sum(axis=1)
Out[179]:
0    2
1    0
2    1
3    1
dtype: int64
```

пример репликации списка и объединения всех элементов в строку:

```
In [180]: ', '.join(['нет числа'] * 3)
Out[180]: 'нет числа, нет числа, нет числа'
```

значения для нового столбца:

```
In [181]: [', '.join(['нет числа'] * x) for x in df.eq('-').sum(axis=1)]
Out[181]: ['нет числа, нет числа', '', 'нет числа', 'нет числа']
```

---

если в DF пропуски (`NaN`):

```
In [34]: df
Out[34]:
     a    b    c
0  1.0  NaN  NaN
1  3.0  4.0  6.0
2  NaN  7.0  4.0
3  6.0  5.0  NaN

In [35]: df['d'] = [', '.join(['нет числа'] * x) for x in df.isnull().sum(axis=1)]

## -- End pasted text --

In [36]: df
Out[36]:
     a    b    c                     d
0  1.0  NaN  NaN  нет числа, нет числа
1  3.0  4.0  6.0
2  NaN  7.0  4.0             нет числа
3  6.0  5.0  NaN             нет числа
```

Comment: MaxU, спасибо! А что если в каждой серии будут разные, но заранее известные ошибки вместо знаков "-" и комментарии в серии d тоже будут разные для ошибки каждой серии вместо однообразного "нет числа"?
Еще, если можно несколько вопросов по вашему решению? Что делает ', '.join(['нет числа'] * x? И .sum(axis=1) может накапливать текстовые значения?

Comment: @DenisNovik, я добавлю пояснения когда доберусь до компьютера. Вы можете пояснить что вы пытаетесь сделать? Т.е. не этот конкретный шаг, а чуть более глобально...

Comment: у меня есть датафрейм, в сериях которого в строках бывают записи типа "Not assigned" или числа которые меньше 10000. Я хотел написать функцию, которая соберет все ошибки в строке каждой серии и человеческим языком в серии d скажет пользователям, что в этой строке в серии a нужно исправить это, в серии b это, а в серии c это. Вот, что пытаюсь реализовать

Comment: большое спасибо за объяснения по моим вопросам. Как всегда четко и доходчиво!

Comment: @DenisNovik, можно сделать более детальные проверки для разных случаев, но для этого понадобится воспроизводимый пример исходного DF и пример того, что вы хотите получить на выходе. Я думаю лучше будет оформить это отдельным вопросом...

Comment: сделал отдельную тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/813083/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5, хотя на мой взгляд они очень похожи.